# SAS two dimensional array

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, sas

What's the best way to understand this code? I'm guessing it's a two dimensional array, but not sure how to follow the steps it takes to get to 140.

This was a base sas practice question, will I need to understand arrays similar to this for the exam?

```
data _null_;
array i{2,3}(1 2 3 4 5 6);
array j{6}(10 20 30 40 50 60);
do k=3,1;
total + i{2,k} -j{2*k};
end;
grandtotal = total + sum (of j{*});
put grandtotal=;
run;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the question asking you to understand:

- 2D array initialization

  - Row major
- 1D array initialization
- Iterative DO loops

  - Can have multiple ranges specified separated by comma
  - A range can be a single value
- SUM statement

  - *`<var> + <expression>;`*

    - equivalent to
      `retain`*`<var>`*`0;`
      *`<var>`*`= sum (`*`<var>`*`,`*`<expression>`*`);`
- Using the `OF` operator to pass a function an array

  - every value in the array is used by the function

Once you understand what all the little pieces do you can mentally step through the code.

```
data _null_;
  * source code formatted so the values are arranged out in row major for ez understanding;
  array i{2,3} (1 2 3
                4 5 6);
  array j{6}(10 20 30 40 50 60);
  do k=3,1;
    total + i{2,k} -j{2*k};
  end;
  grandtotal = total + sum (of j{*});
  put grandtotal=;
run;
```

What are the values as the program steps along ?

- 1st iteration `total = 0 + i{2,3} - j{2*3}`, or `0 + 6 - 60 = -54`
- 2nd iteration `total = -54 + i{2,1) - j{2*1}`, or `-54 + 4 - 20 = -70`
- `grandtotal = -70 + (10 + 20 + 30 + 40 + 50 + 60)`, or `-70 + 210 = 140`

Comment: Thank you, I think I get it now! If I was to change i to i{3,2}, would it be read as 1 2 then 3 4  then 5 6, so i{1,2} would be 2? And k=3 means 3(first iteration) 1(second iteration) for k?